# BASH - any character substitution in file name

Tags: bash

I have some files. The pattern looks like this:

```
FILE_1.TXT
FILE_2.TXT
FILE_3.TXT
```

Now I have a loop where I want to do something with those files. For a reason (the reason is not important for the question), I HAVE to run the loop not through `*.TXT` but through `FILE_*.TXT` - only one thing that is changing in the file names is the number. `FILE_*.TXT` is not working, Bash is looking for `FILE_*.TXT` not for `FILE_1.TXT` etc.

The code I'm using looks like this:

```
for file in FILE_*.TXT
    do
# doing some stuff with the files
    done
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: maybe if you share your code so far someone will be able to tell you what you are doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As paxdiablo has already mentioned, you don't have any files matching the pattern.
You can set a shell option called `nullglob`

```
$ for x in *.doesnotexist; do echo $x; done
*.doesnotexist

$ shopt -s nullglob

$ for x in *.doesnotexist; do echo $x; done
$ (Nothing is printed, the loop does not run.)
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way you'll get `FILE_*.TXT` out of that loop is if none of those files actually *exist:*

```
$ for file in FILE_*.TXT;do echo $file; done
FILE_*.TXT

$ touch FILE_7.TXT

$ for file in FILE_*.TXT;do echo $file; done
FILE_7.TXT
```

So I suggest you look very closely at the patterns and ensure those files *do* exist.

Comment: It seems that I have made a mistake - the files were found by other commands in the loop. The only command that wasnt able to see the REAL file name, instead it said that `FILE_*.TXT` doesnt exist - was... `head` - `head: "FILE_*.TXT" can not be opened for reading: File or directory not found`

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine:

```
$ ls
FILE_1.TXT  FILE_2.TXT  FILE_3.TXT
$ for f in FILE_*.TXT
do
  echo $f
done
FILE_1.TXT
FILE_2.TXT
FILE_3.TXT
```

**Hint:** `file` is an exitsting tool:

```
$ file
Usage: file [-bchikLlNnprsvz0] [--apple] [--mime-encoding] [--mime-type]
            [-e testname] [-F separator] [-f namefile] [-m magicfiles] file ...
       file -C [-m magicfiles]
       file [--help]
```

Use a different variable name, for example `f`.

Comment: I'm pretty certain `bash` can tell the difference between the executable and the variable name :-)

Comment: Sure it can. But to avoid confusin, I recommend not to shadow names.